# Cors with embedded server and spring boot works but not when deploying with tomcat 9

Tags: angular, spring-boot, tomcat9

I'm develloping a web application with angular that is served by an api built with spring boot so obviously I need to enable cors on my server.

I did that with the following classes :

A RestConfig class that contain :

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfig {

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

And my SpringSecurityConfig is as follow :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private MediaUserDetailsService mediaUserDetailsService;
    private MediaUserRepository mediaUserRepository;

    public SpringSecurityConfig(MediaUserDetailsService mediaUserDetailsService, MediaUserRepository userRepository) {
        this.mediaUserDetailsService = mediaUserDetailsService;
        this.mediaUserRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            //enable cors
            .cors()
            .and()
            // remove csrf and state in session because in jwt we do not need them
            .csrf().disable()
            // add jwt filters (1. authentication, 2. authorization)
            .authorizeRequests()
//          // configure access rules
//          .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/media/users").permitAll()
//          .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/media/users").permitAll()
//          .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/login", "/media/users").permitAll()
//          .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login", "/media/users").permitAll();
//          .antMatchers("/media/videos").hasRole("USER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(),  this.mediaUserRepository))
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/media/users");
    }

    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.mediaUserDetailsService);

        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() { return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(); }
}
```

When running the the server code with embedded server (that is by using `mvn spring-boot:run`) my application is working great that is I'm able to do cross origin request and no problem arise.

But I want to host my app on a host which use tomcat 9.0.24. So for testing purpose I installed tomcat 9.0.24 on my laptop. Then I build a war file that I have deployed on it.

And now using the same web app with angular when trying to access an endpoint I get `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/media/users' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

What I don't understand is why is it working with my ebedded server and not when deploying on tomcat. I tried to find some solutions on the web (google is my friend) and stackoverflow but with no luck.

If needed here is the code for the request I send with angular :

```
authenticate(credentials): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(this.API + '/login', credentials, {observe: 'response'});
}
```

Thanks in advance for any response,

Answer (score 0):

If you are not wrapping your angular & spring-boot application as a war file, then you have to define a proxy configuration file in angular root project and configure this file in package.json. so whenever you start angular server, it reads this file and proxies all angular requests to spring-boot api.

proxy.conf.json

```
{
    "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080/<context-path, if you have any>/",
    "secure": false,
    }
}
```

configure this file in package.json

```
"scripts": {
"start":"ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
}
```

start your angular server:

```
ng start
```

check your context-path and your api requests. If your spring-boot api does not stat with /api, use `"pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}` to over-ride api value with empty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but from I read about proxy.conf.json on other articles this solution is only for development or I want to deploy it on production.

Comment: How are you deploying both angular and spring boot, as a war file or both deploying separately?

Comment: Actually I create a war file with my spring boot app that I deploy on tomcat under the folder api and then I build my angular app using ng build --prod and put the generated files under the root folder of tomcat so I realised now that I have no more problem with cors since requests come from the same domain.. Still I wonder why cors issue arised when I was running angular with the webpack dev server.

Comment: Just to understand , You are copying war file in webapps/api/<war> file, copying angular dist file in webapps(root folder)? what do you mean by root folder?

Comment: If you are using maven, Please check below link to wrap angular and spring boot in a war file. Maven will copy angular dist to spring boot resources->static folder. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58887562/spring-boot-war-file-deployed-in-cloud-foundry-throwing-class-not-found-exceptio

Comment: Actually I call my war file api and put it in the webapss folder of tomcat so when it is unzipped it is in a folder called api and I can reach the endpoint with the following urls localhost:8080/api/custom-path and then in the webapss folder there is a ROOT folder where I put the files generated by the ng build command so I can acces my webapp with the url localhost:8080

Comment: After deploying both spring boot war file & angular dist files in tomcat, why are you accessing front end using ```http://localhost:4200```, instead of ```http://localhost:8080```?

Comment: I'm not that's why I have no more cors issue